# how to create a mouseEvent with target in typescript without dispatching?

Tags: typescript, mouseevent, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to create a mouseEvent in typescript
in order to send it forward to primeng event: table.onColumnResizeBegin
I use the mouseEvent constructor
but I can't send a target property to this
and this property is readonly
so the only way I saw
is to dispatch the event on a specific element
and then the element become the target
but I dont want to dispatch the event
is there anther way?